# References to Controls in ContentControl are null at the Parent (Page) Level

Tags: silverlight, xaml, contentcontrol

As a follow up to [this question](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/192263.aspx) where it was suggested I use a ContentControl, I have run into a scenario when I use a custom made class that dervies from ContentControl on a page, any controls defined within that ContentControl are not accessible from the page. All member variables turn out null.

For Instance, say the custom class I created that derives from **ContentControl** is named **MyGroupBox** and I try to use this inside a Page control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApplication.MyUserControl">
   <local:MyGroupBox Title="Basic Information">
      <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" />
   </local:MyGroupBox>
</UserControl>
```

When I try to access MyTextBox from within the Page's code behind, the member variable is null. What is the best workaround for this scenario to get access to these controls so that I can use them in the Page's code behind?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is the Default Template for the MyGroupBox control

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyGroupBox">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyGroupBox">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" Margin="8,8,0,0">
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF979797" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFF1F1F1" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle>
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDFE2ED" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" Margin="10,3,3,3" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

EDIT:

```
public MyUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (this.MyTextBox == null)
    {
        // MyTextBox is null at this point - is there a way to get 
        // the InitializeComponent method to find the control named MyTextBox when
        // it is inside of a ContentControl derived class?
        MessageBox.Show("MyTextBox is null");
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the `MyGroupBox` default template if you have defined one.

Comment: Ok, I added the default template to the question.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem (the TargetType="local:GroupBox" in your xaml I renamed to MyGroupBox but thats not the problem).  This works fine on my machine.  Can you show some content from your MyGroupBox.cs that might be breaking things.  I use a plain derivative of ContentControl with a Title DP.  Are you doing anything else?

Comment: Ok, I uploaded a sample project that demonstrates this problem, you can grab it from here: 
http://andrewgarrison.com/forum/MyApplication.zip

Comment: I think an important element that I left out of the question is that the MyGroupBox control in my project has a XAML resource (that is, I have MyGroupBox.xaml, and MyGroupBox.xaml.cs).

Comment: Open the MyUserControl.g.cs file of the page in VS (use "go to Definition" on InitializeComponent). There must be a line like "this.MyTextBox = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)(this.FindName("MyTextBox")));" Set a breakpoint there and see what happens at construction of your page.

Comment: That method returns null. However, if I change my code such that the MyGroupBox control does not have a XAML page associated with it, then the code does work and does return a valid reference to the textbox.

Comment: When I say remove the XAML associated with the MyGroupBox control, I mean remove the MyGroupBox.xaml and MyGroupBox.xaml.cs and create a new file MyGroupBox.cs that is just code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me step you through putting it together by showing the steps I took to test what you posted:-

- In Visual Studio create a Silverlight Application
- Add a new item to the Silverlight project selecting "Silverlight Templated Control", call this "MyGroupBox".
- Open the Themes\Generic.xaml which will now have been created.  It will contain the a style:-

Generic.Xaml:-

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyGroupBox">
   ...
</Style>
```

- Replace its entire content with the content in your question.
- Edit MyGroupBox.cs, modify to inherit from `ContentControl` and add `Title` dependency property.

MyGroupBox.cs:-

```
public class MyGroupBox : ContentControl
{
    public MyGroupBox()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyGroupBox);
    }

    #region public string Title

    public string Title
    {
        get { return GetValue(TitleProperty) as string; }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                    "Title",
                    typeof(string),
                    typeof(MyGroupBox),
                    new PropertyMetadata(null));
    #endregion public string Title

}
```

- Open MainPage.Xaml add some usage for MyGroupBox

In MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:MyGroupBox Title="Test" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" />
        </local:MyGroupBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

- Edit the MainPage.xaml.cs to test whether `MyTextBox` is null

  ```
  public MainPage()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      MessageBox.Show((MyTextBox == null).ToString());
  }
  ```

I get "False", InitializeComponent has succesfully found the element with the name "MyTextBox".

Comment: Thanks for your effort. The problem was that when I created the MyGroupBox class, I had done so by adding a UserControl to the project (which includes a XAML file - i.e. - MyGroupBox.xaml and MyGroupBox.xaml.cs). What I should have done instead is just added a normal .cs file MyGroupBox.cs and derived from ContentControl in that just as you show in your answer.